# CSV Imported categories not listed in PrestaShop Catolog->Categories

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am using PrestaShop Version 1.6.1.4. 
I have created a CSV for Categories and uploaded it successfully but the catogories and the sub-categories are not shown in Catolog->Categories. When I configure a Module "**Top Horizontal Menu**" in that under Available items Categories can be seen and added to UI as well. When I click on the category in UI 404 error pages comes.
Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

---

The below image is from Top Horizontal Menu Module where JEWELLERY is category and the other below them are sub category.
[image: Top Horizontal Menu]

---

Thw below image shows that the categories CSV is uploaded successfdully

---

[image]

---

But it is not listed under Catolog->Categories refer the below image for this

---

[image]

Comment: I think you have got errors in database after import. If you can't check categories table in MySql (parent ID and shop ID) you can check this: when you are in backoffice `Catalog > categories` add at the end of your page URL "&id_category=3". What do you see?

Comment: If I add "&id_category=3" to the URL of Catalog > categories, I can see "Root" category. In Categories > Root I can See Home and JEWELLERY.
In JEWELLERY all the categories are listed as expected.
What is the issue in DB? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First when I added categories from CSV, the categories is not getting displayed in Catalog->Categories but when I add one category manually then it is displayed in Catalog->Categories but cannot add subcategories to it.

I think there should be some issues in Presta Shop.

---

For example : I manually added "Testing" as one category. It was added as main category by default. Then both "Home" and "Testing" categories can be seen in Catalog ->Categories.
After this I tried to add the subcategories to "Home" categories through CSV, it worked out.

---

PrestaShop is expecting the category to be listed in Catalog->Categories to add the subcategories to it even if that particular category is in DB.
Now I can add the sub categories to what ever Main Categories needed and also the products are also getting listed under the subcategories through CSV.
But I dont know why it is not getting added to Catalog->Categories initially when I add from CSV.

---

Now in DB ps_category table the records are as expected as you have listed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Prestashop ps_category table.]

This is the default Prestashop categories (table `ps_category`). Please check if you have **only one** row with `is_root_category` = 1. This must be  a category ID 2 (`id_category` = 2), your site **Home** category.

And please check if all three categories ID 1, 2, 3 in your table looks the same in columns `id_parent`, `id_shop_default`, `level_depth`, `is_root_category`.